# Сортировка List<>

Tags: c#, winforms, сортировка, list

Привет всем.В `List<T>` есть две целочисленные переменные.Нужно сортировать этот List<> по убыванию одной из них.В данном случае по `RowIndex`;[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Метод `Reverse()` прошу не предлагать ибо эти числа не всегда идут последовательно.Нужна именно сортировка по убыванию.Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Немного более эффективный вариант должен быть [такой](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w56d4y5z.aspx):

```
list.Sort((l, r) => r.RowIndex.CompareTo(l.RowIndex));
```

Comment: Спасибо.Это так же работает.

Comment: @ლუკა ბერიანიძე: Пожалуйста!

Answer (score 1):

Проблема решена.Использовал List<> = List<>.OrderByDescending(...).ToList();